# Where to add a potentiometer to vary input voltage to comparator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, comparator

The attached circuit and description was originally from another website.

The circuit as it is keeps the buzzer off until the FSR reaches 26  kΩ (light force), then turns it on until it reaches 10 kΩ (heavy force) then turns it off again. I would like to be able to adjust the point at which it turns off at the heavy force point (of 2.5 V).

My question is: Where can I add a pot to vary the 10 kΩ/2.5 V value that's input into the [TLV1702](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv1702.pdf)?

A quick demo is in [this YouTube short](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/MElcl9LruXY).
The full schematic is shown below.

Thanks.

Source: [Practical Machinist - "O/T - Electronic circuit help?"](https://www.practicalmachinist.com/forum/threads/o-t-electronic-circuit-help.417884/#post-4129824), post by [Fred Hern](https://www.practicalmachinist.com/forum/members/fred-hern.185501/)

> [image: circuit]
>
> In the circuit shown the voltage from the FSR varies between 2.5 V and 3.6 V as the FSR resistance varies from 10 k to 26 k. When the voltage is less than 2.5 V, the lower comparator holds the transistor base at ground; when the voltage is greater than 3.6 V, the upper comparator holds the transistor base at ground. In between these values, the 1 k resistor turns on the transistor, turning on the buzzer.

Comment: You could provide the reference voltages for IN- and IN+ by two independent potentiometers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in one of the comments you cannot place a pot on the input signal to change one detection point. Doing so would offset both your high and low points. You need to adjust the set-point voltages on the comparator inputs instead.

You didn't mention how much of an adjustment you needed so here are 3 options that should work. (Just the resistor divider section is shown.)

Arrangement "B" allows just the 2.5V set-point to be adjusted.

Arrangement "C" allow both the 3.6V and the 2.5V set-points to be adjusted.

Arrangement "D" again allows both set-points to be adjusted but with a single pot on each line, (as in the comment by Jens).

Note that for "D" if using a single pot for each set-point a fine adjustment may be a bit difficult to obtain, unless you were to use multi-turn pots.

In arrangements B and C the center point of each 2k pot will be fairly close to your original set-point voltages.

The lines showing two voltage levels indicates the upper and lower range of the pot adjustments.

[image]
.

Comment: Thank you so much Ned, arrangement B is exactly what I want.  I found this applet for changing the values and think I'll try a 5K pot with 10K fixed resistors on either side to give an output of 2-3v, I'll have to experiment to get the results I'm looking for.  https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzAsBOJyWoGwgIxkgJhrgOyEDMYAHLmkoSAKwR32MCmAtJpgFABKIChDJjQQBQzLnBS4jKRBx0uAJ36CsI1Rly44U7bC4B3fgkk6InfCHPXlm63QxiQJKxBLYYXTIV3Ptfmq4jlhYsPLQYEw8LADOAJaxAC4AhgB2AMYsXADm9q6iaiQkGPJ2AS4l1jogcMJSnmBcQA

Comment: Looking closer that applet only works if the two comparator lines are separated, could you explain how you came up with the resistance values in your example B & C?  Just trying to understand.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Jim Kailey - The added pot just replaces a portion of the original adjacent resistors, for example the 2k pot takes about 1k from the resistor above it & 1k from the resistor below it. Balancing it with that simple method insures that the original set-point voltage is near the center of the pot. The original string resistance is also maintained, if that was important. It doesn't necessarily need to be done that way, you could calculate all new exact values. But after all that you would likely end up with non-standard resistor values, (as in the original circuit the 4.4k is a non-standard).

Comment: @Jim Kailey - If you feel the answer satisfies your initial question you can click on the grey check mark to the side of the answer, this will close out the question.

Comment: Thanks again Nedd, you have been most helpful!